# JimFS: how to get File from Path

Tags: java, jimfs

I started using google jimfs and I can't understand how I can get file from path. In source code I see that Path.toFile throws UnsupportedOperationException. But how then can I use it without files? For example if my application need to know if some path is folder or file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSR 203 API has all the tools you need for that; and in this case, [the `Files` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

In spite of its name, it handles everything `Path`. For instance, you can use:

```
Files.isDirectory(thePath)
```

to test whether a file is a directory. But there are also other ways to test for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! But why did they do like that?

Comment: Precisely because a `Path` can be issued from different filesystems. The `Path` class is "busy" enough as it is without adding more methods to it...

Comment: Do I understand you right - because Path can be linked to different file systems and File can't?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A `File` can only be issued from what JSR 203 calls the default filesystem -- see `FileSystems.getDefault()`. In fact, when you do `Paths.get(whatever)`, this is exactly equivalent to `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(whatever)`.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer!

Comment: @JimJim2000: Yeah, as fge indicates, it's basically impossible to get a `File` object for something other than the default file system, so you can't have an in-memory file system like Jimfs and use `File`. That's part of the reason the new API (`Path`, `Files`, etc.) was created.

Comment: I don't understand why someonee downvoted my question. Is my question stupid?

Comment: @JimJim2000: Maybe because they thought you should have researched the API you were using more before asking a question about it? I don't know... I wouldn't worry about it.